# Bitwise Operations on type byte vs byte[]

Tags: java, types, byte, bitwise-operators, encryption-symmetric

Here is the bit of code I'm working with:

```
byte[] encodedBytes1 = null;
byte[] encodedBytes2 = null;
try {
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(encryptationMode);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    encodedBytes1 = c.doFinal(TestText1.getBytes());
    encodedBytes2 = c.doFinal(TestText2.getBytes());
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Log.e(TAG, "AES encryption error");
}
byte[] encodedHomo = null;
boolean encoded1_2 = TestText1.getBytes() || TestText2.getBytes();
```

So I'm trying to do bitwise operations on `encodedBytes1` and `encodedBytes2` and make that new value `encodedHomo` (my project is homomorphic encryption on AES algorithm). Why can't I perform bitwise operation operations on type `byte[]`? What is, if any, the difference between the type `byte` and `byte[]`?

Comment: One is a primitive and the other is an object containing an array of `bytes`  They don't have any method or functionality in common.

Comment: You can use a loop and do it byte-wise.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a bitwise OR between two byte arrays you need to do this for each byte.

```
public static byte[] bitwiseOr(byte[] bytes1, byte[] bytes2) {
    if (bytes1.length < bytes2.length)
       return bitwiseOr(bytes2, bytes1);
    // bytes1 is never shorter than bytes2
    byte[] ret = bytes1.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes2.length; i++)
        ret[i] |= bytes2[i];
    return ret;
}
```

Note: there is no `||` operation for two `byte` or two `byte[]` There is only `|` for two `byte`

Comment: With `&` I would take the `min` of the lengths too, but with `|` I would take the `max` and just copy the remainder of the longer array.

Comment: @maraca I have updated my answer to take the longer length.

Answer (score -1):

Bitwise operations work on primitive data types, an array is not a primitive data type.

The bitwise OR operation, for example, has a well defined behavior for numbers but not for compound objects (which are not simply *'made of bits'*).

Answer (score -1):

Java ain't C. Your `byte[]` objects aren't pointers to lots of bits.

You have to do your bitwise ops on *each* `byte` in the `byte[]`s spearately.

Comment: You can't do that in C either. ;)